# Can Ruby Octokit (GitHub API) be used to commit changes directly into a GitHub repository?

Tags: ruby, git, github, octokit

I would like to use the Ruby octokit gem to apply changes to a GitHub repository. This would be Ruby 2 (not Rails).

I have used the API to authenticate and look at existing committed objctes: trees and blobs. What I don't understand is how I go about updating, adding and removing parts of the repository.

Using the `git` command-line tool, I would clone the repo, copy the changed files over the top and then do a `git add -A .` at the top level before committing and pushing the change out. Doing it that way is quite straightforward. I've written some Ruby code that does this via system calls to the underlying git tools.

However, I'd like to understand the API and perform the updates directly without cloning and pushing. I have read some background [here](http://mattgreensmith.net/2013/08/08/commit-directly-to-github-via-api-with-octokit) and [here](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2011/07/23/digging-around-the-github-api-take-2.html) that demonstrate that it is possible but they only go as far as adding a single file.

I wrote some code to traverse the directory and upload blobs for everything, hoping it didn't matter when those blobs computed the same sha value. But I think this is really inefficient and there must be a better way, perhaps comparing sha values locally before posting them. Or perhaps the API includes an equivalent to `git add -A` that I have missed.

If anyone knows how to do this or can point me at appropriate examples that would help. I will post an answer myself when I work it out.